# Set all documents with libre office to be editable by default?

Tags: libreoffice

i'm downloading documents and spreadsheets daily, and it seems like 100% of them are set as read-only.  i can start editing them with just 2 clicks, but it's mildly annoying.  can i set all documents to be editable by default?

my version is:

```
Version: 7.2.3.2 / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 20(Build:2)
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 5.13; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Ubuntu package version: 1:7.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
Calc: threaded
```

Comment: What do the "two clicks" do, that enable you to make the files editable?

Comment: What are the ownership and permission settings for the files you can't open?

Comment: @waltinator thanks, this was helpful.  it looks like they're `-rw-rw-r--` if saved to `~/documents/` but `-r--------` when saved to `/tmp/mozilla_user0/`.  can i change the default permissions for `/tmp/mozilla_user0/`?